# filter array of objects based on objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

I would like to know how to filter array of objects in javascript.

How to filter based on condition -

`count` should be greater than 0 for both `w1` and `w2` objects

and `totalcount` should be greater than 2 .

But instead of specifying w1 or w2 , is there any other way to do this, because there will be w1, w2, w3... wn times

```
function getObject (obj1){
  var result = obj1.filter(e=>e.totalcount > 2 && e.w1.count > 0 && e.w2.count > 0);
  return result;
}
var output = this.getObject(obj1);

var obj1=[
 {
"memberid": "s1",
"w1":{"count": 1, "qty": 1},
"w2":{"count": 0, "qty": 0},
 ... wn
"totalcount": 1
 },
{
"memberid": "s2",
"w1":{"count": 2, "qty": 2, "amount": 400.0},
"w2":{"count": 3, "qty": 2, "amount": 503.0},
 ... wn
"totalcount": 5
},
{
"memberid": "s3",
"w1":{"count": 3, "qty": 2, "amount": 0.0},
"w2":{"count": 3, "qty": 4, "amount": 503.0},
 ... wn
"totalcount": 6
}
]
```

Expected Output

```
[
{
"memberid": "s2",
"w1":{"count": 2, "qty": 2, "amount": 400.0},
"w2":{"count": 3, "qty": 2, "amount": 503.0},
"totalcount": 5
},
{
"memberid": "s3",
"w1":{"count": 3, "qty": 2, "amount": 0.0},
"w2":{"count": 3, "qty": 4, "amount": 503.0},
"totalcount": 6
}

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()`, and then `spread operator` to get all the "w's" and using `Object.values()` to get an array of those, and use `some()` to check if there is any `count` that equals to 0.
and also check the value of `totalcount` property

```js
var arr = [
    {
  "memberid": "s1",
  "w1":{"count": 1, "qty": 1},
  "w2":{"count": 0, "qty": 0}, 
  "totalcount": 1
    },
  {
  "memberid": "s2",
  "w1":{"count": 2, "qty": 2, "amount": 400.0},
  "w2":{"count": 3, "qty": 2, "amount": 503.0}, 
  "totalcount": 5
  },
  {
  "memberid": "s3",
  "w1":{"count": 3, "qty": 2, "amount": 0.0},
  "w2":{"count": 3, "qty": 4, "amount": 503.0},
  "totalcount": 6
  }
 ]

 const res = arr.filter(({ memberid, totalcount, ...rest }) => {
    return !Object.values(rest).some(({ count }) => count === 0) && totalcount > 2;
 })

 console.log(res);
```

references:

[filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) 
[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) 
[some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: thanks how to filter based on condition if all week object count is greater than 1

Comment: @codecat if you want greater than 1, just change the condition in my code to `count <= 1` instead of `count === 0`

Answer (score 0):

You van use filter over your array. For checking counts I use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Because I don't know which keys are present I use a regex which hits on all "w" + a number.

```js
function getObject (obj1){
  var result = obj1.filter(e=> {
      if (e.totalcount <= 2) 
          return false;
      return Object.keys(e).every(key => !key.match(/^w[0-9]+$/) || e[key].count>0);
  });
  return result;
}

var obj1=[
 {
"memberid": "s1",
"w1":{"count": 1, "qty": 1},
"w2":{"count": 0, "qty": 0},
"totalcount": 1
 },
{
"memberid": "s2",
"w1":{"count": 2, "qty": 2, "amount": 400.0},
"w2":{"count": 3, "qty": 2, "amount": 503.0},
"totalcount": 5
},
{
"memberid": "s3",
"w1":{"count": 3, "qty": 2, "amount": 0.0},
"w2":{"count": 3, "qty": 4, "amount": 503.0},
"totalcount": 6
},
{
"memberid": "s4",
"w1":{"count": 2, "qty": 2, "amount": 400.0},
"w2":{"count": 3, "qty": 4, "amount": 503.0},
"w3":{"count": 2, "qty": 2, "amount": 400.0},
"w4":{"count": -3, "qty": 4, "amount": 503.0},
"totalcount": 6
}
];

console.log(getObject (obj1));
```

Comment: Hi Sascha, thanks how to filter based on condition if all week object count is greater than 1